# How to upload multiple images/files along with a @Body in Retrofit using @MultiPart

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to submit large data (nested json objects) along with multiple images/files using @POST in Retrofit.

One easy/hacky way is to convert the images to base64 string & put in inside a RequestBody & send it without using @Multipart. Another way is to use `@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody>`. to attach some data along with the image. This works if the data is less. But I have a huge nested RequestBody like this:

```
{
  "id": "id12",
  "bar": {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "asd"
  }
} .....
```

But how to send the body along with images using @Multipart.

```
@Multipart
@POST("api/upload")
Observable<SubmitResponse> submitData(@Body Foo foo, @Part MultipartBody.Part[] files);

class Foo {

    @SerializedName("book_id")
    @Expose
    private String book_id;
    @SerializedName("bar")
    @Expose
    private Bar anotherBodyinsideFoo;

}
```

The above method throws an error: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.

Give a suggestion on how to upload multiple files along with a Request body (@Body Foo) in Retrofit.

Comment: one of the option is upload image as Base64.

Comment: Yeah, right now I'm doing that only. But I wanted to do it via @MultiPart

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code for upload multiple image using **Retrofit**

```
@POST(UPLOAD_EVENT)
    Call<EventResponse> uploadEvent(@Header("Authorization") String auth, @Body RequestBody body);

 MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("event_name", eventName);
    builder.addFormDataPart("location", loacation);
    builder.addFormDataPart("longitude", longitude);
    builder.addFormDataPart("latitude", latitude);
    builder.addFormDataPart("is_private", isPublic);
    builder.addFormDataPart("caption", caption);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), coverImage);
    builder.addFormDataPart("cover_image", coverImage.getName(), requestBody);
    RequestBody requestBody1 = null;

    for (int i = 0, size = eventFiles.size(); i < size; i++) {
        requestBody1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), eventFiles.get(i));
        builder.addFormDataPart("album_images" + "[" + i + "]", eventFiles.get(i).getName(), requestBody1);
    }
    RequestBody finalRequestBody = builder.build();

    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestClient.ROOT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestClient.NetworkCall networkCall = retrofit.create(RestClient.NetworkCall.class);

    Call<EventResponse> response = networkCall.uploadEvent(Prefs.getAuth(App.getContext()), finalRequestBody);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<EventResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EventResponse> call, Response<EventResponse> response) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
            if (response.code() == Constant.SUCCESS_STATUS) {

                if (response.body() != null) {
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Constant.REFRESH_FEEDS));
                    Log.e("Success", "Success");
                }
            } else {
                Converter<ResponseBody, EventResponse> converter =
                        retrofit.responseBodyConverter(EventResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
                try {
                    if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                        EventResponse errorResponse = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                        Log.e("Failure", "Failure");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EventResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
            Log.e("Failure", "Failure");
        }
    });
```